# CSS: Inset shadow by parenting div over iframe

Tags: html, iframe, css

I'd like to achieve an effect of a shadowed iframe element by its parenting div element.

HTML

`<div>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zdOmNiXvM3w?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>`

CSS

```
div {
    box-shadow: 
    inset 0px 11px 8px -10px black,
    inset 0px -11px 8px -10px black;
}
```

The above is what I've got so far, but the iframe appears to take priority regardless of using z-index in CSS.
I've used a Youtube iframe in this example, but this solution also needs to work with standard iframes, such as one to google.
Ideally using only CSS/HTML.

Comment: That is because the `<iframe>` element will always be above the box shadow no matter what. To overcome this issue, place an overlay (with a pseudo-element or an element), and set the element to be non-responsive to the cursor, using `pointer-events: none`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The iframe will always be above the box-shadow of its parent. To counter this issue, you can assign the box-shadow to a pseudo-element positioned absolutely within the parent element, and make it non-responsive to pointer events:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div iframe {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
div::before {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5); // Added only to show overlay, can be removed
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 8px -10px black, inset 0px -11px 8px -10px black;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I've added the slightly transparent white background to show the overlay. You can always remove it. See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/uva5zkrg/

Comment: +1, but you can spare a few z-index :) http://jsfiddle.net/uva5zkrg/1/ and even use none, relative is enough to bring up front :) http://jsfiddle.net/uva5zkrg/2/

Comment: Nice trick, however the browser support of `pointer-events` is not that good which may or may not meet the OP's need.

Comment: @HashemQolami , good that it filters IE8 with `::` , useless if no background  is applied to pseudo that should be then , translucide to pointer-events ... in theorie :).

Comment: @GCyrillus I didn't understand the word `translucide`. I'm not a native English speaker but it seems that it's not an English word :) Anyway, I should note that `pointer-events` is not supported in IE10 and below in a (X)HTML context.

Comment: @HashemQolami , sorry for that funny word, it means transparent somehow, here you would see through and it should not stand in the way :) (english is far to be my mother language too. correct me people

Comment: This works perfectly, but unfortunately not for my specific case as I'm already using :before and :after on my parent div to make it full width, using the example here. I'd like to make div both full width (like the h2 element does in this example) and inset shadowed. Many thanks.  http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Comment: @Joe If that is the case, you might have to rely on JS to insert a empty DOM element to emulate the pseudo-element.