# Is there anything I can do to remove the 1px border appearing around this SoundCloud widget?

Tags: ios, css, widget, border, soundcloud

[As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhm3K.jpg)
, there is a 1px border around the widget. It only appears on iOS. I can see the CSS that's causing this in the inspector:

```
.widget {
  ...
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  ...
}
```

This is the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/307068209&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" scrolling="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I know CSS can't effect elements coming from a different domain in an iframe, but client says it looks bad. Is there something that I might be doing to cause this to appear? If not, is there a way I can remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking advice from this post:

[CSS: Inset shadow by parenting div over iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474276/css-inset-shadow-by-parenting-div-over-iframe)

And added this bad boy:

```
.iframe-wrapper:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Which hides the border well enough

Answer (score 0):

You could hide/clip the outermost 1px of the entire iframe, but that may or may not have a desirable effect. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evKLMr

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:398px;
  height:198px;
}

iframe {
  position: relative;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
frameborder="no"
```

rather than

```
frameborder="0"
```